# Can I print a standard test page in code-behind in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

Is there a way to print a standard test page in WPF from C# code if I have the name of a network printer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example of using the System.Management namespace to access WMI and print a Test Page to a Printer.  This relies on the Printer being connected to the Computer, I can provide code for connecting a Network printer through System.Management if you want that as well.  This code should work for any version of the .Net Framework

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public class PrintTestPageUsingWMI
{
    private String _name;
    private ManagementObject _printer = null;

    public PrintTestPageUsingWMI(String printerName)
    {
        this._name = printerName;

        //Find the Win32_Printer which is a Network Printer of this name

        //Declare WMI Variables
        ManagementObject MgmtObject;
        ManagementObjectCollection MgmtCollection;
        ManagementObjectSearcher MgmtSearcher;

        //Perform the search for printers and return the listing as a collection
        MgmtSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Printer");
        MgmtCollection = MgmtSearcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject objWMI in MgmtCollection)
        {
            if (objWMI.Item("sharename").ToString().Equals(this._name))
            {
                this._printer = objWMI;
            }
        }

        if (this._printer == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Selected Printer is not connected to this Computer");
        }        
    }

    public void PrintTestPage()
    {
        this.InvokeWMIMethod("PrintTestPage");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper Method which Invokes WMI Methods on this Printer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">The name of the WMI Method to Invoke</param>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private void InvokeWMIMethod(String method) {
        if (this._printer == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't Print a Test Page on a Printer which is not connected to the Computer");
        }

        Object[] objTemp = new Object[0] { null };
        ManagementObject objWMI;

        //Invoke the WMI Method
        this._printer.InvokeMethod(method, objTemp);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could look at the System.Printing Namespace which is supported in .Net 3.0 and higher

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using prnadmin.dll.  You most probably will have to create the printer in windows first (either by code or with the user interface) if it's not already configured on the workstation.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321025

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PrinterAdmin.aspx?display=Print