# how to print Test page on a Printer?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am new to `C#` and I am using windows forms, windows 7 and .Net 4.0. 
I have 3 printers connected to my computer I want to print windows test page on a specific printer. All printers names are listed in `ComboBox` as shown in the following code I want to select a printer from `ComboBox` and print test page.

I had a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858442/can-i-print-a-standard-test-page-in-code-behind-in-net-3-5/858567#858567), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710196/how-to-print-test-page-on-default-printer) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677034/how-to-print-a-test-page-and-capture-the-return-value-for-a-non-default-printer) but nothing helped.

Does anyone know how to do it?

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    comboBox_Printers.Items.Add(printer);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Could you post a sample of your code that would reproduce the error?

Comment: Each driver is different. I will most likely only work for few printer models. Why don't you create your own print test page and send it to the correct printer ? Plus printing test page sometime have screen dialog specific to your printer. Like mine at home i get to choose which test i want to use and quality test. Total 6 test possible. It's much easy to right click on the printer and chose print test page or whatever option available for that specific printer model.

Comment: Leonardo Alves Machado- I really do not have any code.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this method might look *verbose*, but I think it's important, when calling `WMI` methods, that the Management Options and Scopes are defined correctly.
This gives means to correct/adapt the code to specific contexts, when necessary.
Also, the helper methods here can be reused to initialize any other `WMI` query.

For example, a wrong **`Impersonation`** option, will result in an exception (`0x80070005: (E_ACCESSDENIED)`) when connecting to the `WMI` `Scope` or when the `WMI` query is executed.

A description of the **`PrintTestPage`** method parameters:

**`string PrinterName`**:  the name of a specific Printer or `null` to use the default Printer.
**`string MachineName`**:  the name of a Machine in the Network or `null` to use the **`LocalMachine`** name.

The method returns `0` if successful and throws an exception if the Printer is not found.

Sample call to Print a test page using the default printer in the local machine:

```
var result = PrintTestPage(null, null);
```

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

public static uint PrintTestPage(string PrinterName, string MachineName)
{
    ConnectionOptions connOptions = GetConnectionOptions();
    EnumerationOptions mOptions = GetEnumerationOptions(false);
    string machineName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(MachineName) ? Environment.MachineName : MachineName;
    ManagementScope mScope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{machineName}\root\CIMV2", connOptions);
    SelectQuery mQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
    mQuery.QueryString += string.IsNullOrEmpty(PrinterName) 
                        ? " WHERE Default = True" 
                        : $" WHERE Name = '{PrinterName}'";
    mScope.Connect();

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mScope, mQuery, mOptions))
    {
        ManagementObject moPrinter = moSearcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (moPrinter is null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Printer not found");

        InvokeMethodOptions moMethodOpt = new InvokeMethodOptions(null, ManagementOptions.InfiniteTimeout);
        using (ManagementBaseObject moParams = moPrinter.GetMethodParameters("PrintTestPage"))
        using (ManagementBaseObject moResult = moPrinter.InvokeMethod("PrintTestPage", moParams, moMethodOpt))
            return (UInt32)moResult["ReturnValue"];
    }
}
```

Helper methods:

```
private static EnumerationOptions GetEnumerationOptions(bool DeepScan)
{
    EnumerationOptions mOptions = new EnumerationOptions()
    {
        Rewindable = false,        //Forward only query => no caching
        ReturnImmediately = true,  //Pseudo-async result
        DirectRead = true,         //Skip superclasses
        EnumerateDeep = DeepScan   //No recursion
    };
    return mOptions;
}

private static ConnectionOptions GetConnectionOptions()
{
    ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions()
    {
        EnablePrivileges = true,
        Timeout = ManagementOptions.InfiniteTimeout,
        Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
        Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
    };
    return connOptions;
}
```